# Error utilizando JPA: vax.naming.NoInitialContextException

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Pues mi situación es la siguiente. Estoy trabajando en un proyecto final que tengo que entregar mañana junto a un amigo. Estamos trabajando a la par. No sé qué pasó, de un momento a otro me sale el siquiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.carrito.dao.implement.singleton.EntityManagerSingleton.getInstanceEntityManager(EntityManagerSingleton.java:23)
    at com.carrito.controller.interfaces.implement.PublicadorDAOImpl.<init>(PublicadorDAOImpl.java:16)
    at com.carrito.servlet.controller.usuario.Prueba.main(Prueba.java:36)
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carritodb?l [root on Default schema]]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(InitialContext.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:135)
    ... 23 more
```

Como ven, tengo una clase prueba, para probar si guarda a medida que vamos trabajando:

```
package com.carrito.servlet.controller.usuario;

import com.carrito.controller.interfaces.implement.PublicadorDAOImpl;
import com.carrito.model.Publicador;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author david
 */
public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date fecha = new Date("12/09/2016");
        Publicador pub = new Publicador(), pub2 = new Publicador(), pub3 = new Publicador();

//        pub.setNombrePublicador("Mariano");
//        pub.setApellidoPublicador("Rodríguez");
//        pub.setUbicacionCarrito("Piedra blanca");
//        pub.setFechaPublicador(fecha);
//        
//        pub2.setNombrePublicador("Raymond");
//        pub2.setApellidoPublicador("Pozo");
//        pub2.setUbicacionCarrito("Parte atrás");
//        pub2.setFechaPublicador(fecha);

        pub3.setNombrePublicador("Maria");
        pub3.setApellidoPublicador("César");
//        pub3.setUbicacionCarrito("Las Espinas, Espaillat");

        PublicadorDAOImpl pubImp = new PublicadorDAOImpl();
        pubImp.guardar(pub3);


    }
}
```

Espero que si a alguno de ustedes les ha dado este error, me ayuden a solucionarlo por favor, ya voy a llorar

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Carrito_1.2PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>carritodb</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.carrito.model.Horario</class>
    <class>com.carrito.model.Jornada</class>
    <class>com.carrito.model.Carrito</class>
    <class>com.carrito.model.Publicador</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `stacktrace`

> Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify
>   class name in environment or system property, or as an applet
>   parameter, or in an application resource file: 
>   java.naming.factory.initial

Le está diciendo que necesita datos de configuración para poder realizar los procedimientos necesarios.Sí, JPA puede manejar la configuración por medio de `persistence.xml` pero ud tiene que darle la información necesaria para que pueda funcionar.

Hay que entender que JPA es una **especificación**, en otras palabras, JPA lo que hace es establecer las reglas (interfaces) pero necesita de alguien que implemente esas reglas como `Hibernate` o `EclipseLink`, por eso ud especifica un proveedor `<provider />` que en su caso lo hace con eclipselik:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Pero **dónde estan los datos de conexión a la DB ?** un archivo `persistence.xml` debe ir mas o menos así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Tienda_V4.2PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>    
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>           
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombre_base_de_datos"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>        
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

En mi caso, estoy utilizando `Hibernate` como implementación.

Algo importante a saber es el `transaction-type` que puede ser `JTA` o `RESOURCE_LOCAL`.

### RESOURCE_LOCAL

Uno se encarga de la administración del `Persistence Unit` a través del `EntityMAnagerFactory`.

### JTA

El servidor de aplicaciónes JavaEE como por ejemplo `Glassfish, Weblogic, WildFly, TomEE` son los que se encargan del `Persistence Unit` y nosotros lo podemos [inyectar](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/usclient005.htm#CIHIAHIE) a través de:

```
@persistenceContext(unitNAme="nombre_persiste_unit")   
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Una pregunta mi amigo @esteban. Estoy usando Tomcat, y me gustaría saber si es en el mismo `persistence.xml` que debo inyectar esa instrucción de _JTA_

Comment: Estoy buscando que mi WebApp guarde aunque la suba a un servidor, que no dependa de mí. ¿Pero qué manera me conviene más, dado que es un proyecto final?

Comment: Tomcat no es un servidor de aplicaciones javaEE, es un contenedor de servlets por lo que EJBs no los soporta, por ende JTA tampoco debería que yo sepa; le tocaría RESOURCE_LOCAL